# LINQ - Sorting by using OrderBy on a nullable field

Tags: linq

I'm trying to sort a collection of type `Enumerable<DataRow>` by using LINQ's OrderBy method on a nullable Int32 field. Because some of the values of this field are null, Visual studio throws a System.ArgumentException with message 'Object must be of type Int32.' Here is the problematic line of code:

```
collection1 = collection1.OrderBy(row => row["Column1"]);
```

where Column1 is the nullable Int32 field and the variable `collection1` is declared as:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> collection1;
```

Is there a way to rewrite the above line so that it ignores the nulls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
collection1.OrderBy(row => row.Field<int?>("Column1"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the ternary conditional operator:

```
collection1 = collection1.OrderBy(row => 
  row["Column1"] != null ? row["Column1"] : low_priority_indicator);
```

Where `low_priority_indicator` is an integer representing a standard, low-order (in respect to your priorities) value. Otherwise you could filter out the `null` values *before* ordering, if you want to exclude entirely from the resulting collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
collection1 = collection1.Where(row => row["Column1"] != null).
    OrderBy(row => row["Column1"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will ignore the values - try this:

```
collection1 = collection1
                .Where(c => c["Column1"].HasValue)
                .OrderBy(row => row["Column1"]);
```